# Spring MVC form prepopulate or get value from readonly input tag

Tags: html, forms, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form with all fields, less one of it, filled from user. This is the class passed through the form

```
public class CarForm {

    private String id;
    private Integer initialKm;
    private String carChassis;
    private String note;
    private String carType;
    private Integer fleet;
```

The only one field, `fleet`, I would like to set before pass the form, or better, set it from HTML. For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Fleet application</label> <input type="text"
      class="form-control" th:field="*{fleet}"    
      th:placeholder="${fleetApplication}" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

So I would like to show `${fleetApplication.application}` and set into `fleet` this value, or, if it is possible, set another value`${fleetApplication.idFleet}`.
Is it possible one of these solutions?Thanks

Update: as suggested by @Faraj Farook I resolved so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Fleet application</label>
    <!-- Show fleet application -->
    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:value="${fleetApplication.application}" readonly="readonly" />
  <!-- Save into fleet the value of idFleet -->
   <input type="hidden" name="fleet" th:value="${fleetApplication.idFleet}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting it in the server side**

controller

```
String action(Model model){
   CarForm carForm =  new CarForm();
   carForm.setFleet(<some value>);
   model.addAttribute("obj", carForm);
   return view.html;
}
```

view.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Fleet application</label> 
    <input type="text" th:field="*{fleet}" readonly/>
</div>
```

**setting it in the client side**

view.html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Fleet application</label> 
    <input type="text" readonly th:value="${someValueVariable}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="fleet" th:value="${someValueVariable}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: with the client side it doesn't show the value of variable and the returned value of fleet is null. If I use th:text it shows the value but out of the box and returns null anyway
The server side method I have already tried, it return null for fleet value

Comment: use th:value not the th:placeholder.. btw i think this is because it'd getting overriden by the value in th:field. use it as above. I changed the answer a little bit